# Conceptually (and loosely), is a struct similar to a (vb) constant?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a VB/asp classic background.  Regarding structs, in an abstract sense, are they similar to constants?  In other words, are Structs to constants what Classes are to variables (in a very loose way)?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/struct-versus-class

Comment: Thanks a_schimpf. I like the angle this comes from.

Answer (score 3):

I would say you have a *very loose* understanding of all of those concepts. A `struct`, [by definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), is:

> ... a value type that can contain constructors, constants, fields, methods, properties, indexers, operators, events, and nested types.

So, in terms of association, a `struct` is much more like a `class` because a `class` can contain all of the aforementioned and more. But, there is a **very distinct difference,** and it has to do with how the instances are passed around. A `struct` is explicitly passed *by value* because it's a `value type`, whereas a `class` is passed *by reference* because it is a `reference type`. Further, to clarify what was stated by Asik, `value types` are *sometimes* stored on the stack, but could be stored on the heap if they are part of a container like a `class`. Here is a **fantastic** blog really breaking that down [by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx).

Now, to deal with your comparison of `constants` and `variables` **(though you didn't directly compare them, I'm going to)**. A `constant` **is in fact** a `variable`, and nowhere near a `struct`. In fact, [by definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), a `constant` is:

> ... a declaration of a field or local variable. It specifies that the value of the field or the local variable is constant, which means it cannot be modified.

Comment: It might be worth noting that a `const` is set at compile time. So the type and the value is known at compile time. That's also the difference to a `static readonly` field.

Comment: Thanks all. A poorly worded question probably, because I think I have misrepresented myself.  I am aware that structs are very similar to classes etc. I guess I am meaning in terms of use, with structs 'ideally' being immutable.  In that sense I was comparing them to constants. I don't think a struct is a constant, but the way it is used reminded me of it being almost the 'object equivalent' of a constant.  Conceptually only, not literally.

Comment: It's not correct to say "a struct is placed on the stack instead of the heap"; this only concerns local variables. Class fields will live on the heap inside their containing object.

Comment: No, if the struct is a field of a reference type, then it will live on the heap inside this object, as I said. Static readonly structs would also not live on the stack. Your statement is only true for local variables and function parameters.

Comment: @Asik, I did some more studying and found that first, you are correct and that second, I was a bit enlightened and referenced one of the best blogs ever written on the topic.

Comment: @PercivalSmashmouth, but even conceptually it's not like a `const` because a `struct` is **not** immutable.

Comment: @Michael Not necessarily immutable, agreed, though I've read that ideally they 'ought to be' even if they don't 'have to be'. Perhaps a little too 'out there' a comparison for a question on here as the wavelength I'm on isn't transcribing well but I've enjoyed reading the answers.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, would you mind sharing a link to the blog you mentioned?

Comment: @PercivalSmashmouth, the link to blog is actually in my edited question, it's wrapped around the `Eric Lippert` text.

Comment: A constant is not a variable. "Constant" and "can vary" are opposites. That documentation is *terrible*; thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @EricLippert, gladly! And also, thank you very much for the clarification too!

Answer (score 3):

No Structs are more like a lightweight classes. User defined type would be a closer parallel, a variable can point to an instance of a class or a struct.

The really important bit is a struct is a value type, so more like int than MyClass.

so if you did something like

```
v = new MyStruct(16);
w = v;
w.somevalue = 14;
v.somevalue would still be 16
```

where as if MyStruct was my class w and v would point to the same instance of my class.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful.  It is in this way that a struct reminds me of a constant in a sense, because it is immutable.

Comment: Um you need to be careful with these simplifications. Immutable and constant aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

No.
Structs/Structures are Value types (passed by value) whereas Classes are Reference types (passed by reference).

So:

```
class Program{
    static void main(){
        MyStruct testStruct; //we don't need a constructor for a struct
        testStruct.p_var = 10;
        change(testStruct);
        Console.WriteLine(testStruct.p_var);
    }

    static void change(MyStruct test){
        test.p_var = 20;
    }
}

struct MyStruct{
    public int p_var;
}
```

will print `10`

Changing MyStruct to a Class would require a constructor (even if it doesn't do anything) and cause the program to print `20` instead.

There are performance considerations when using Structs. Whilst the GC doesn't generally have to get involved (since value types can go on the stack), if you pass structs as parameters by value, the entire struct has to be copied and passed through. Passing a class as a parameter is a lightweight operation in comparison, since that's just passing a simple reference.

Comment: `Changing MyStruct to a Class would require a constructor...`, it's probably worth noting that you **don't** need to actually code or define the default `ctor` with no parameters if it doesn't do anything.